# Using "SELECT FOR UPDATE OF" with Hibernate 4 & Postgres

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-mapping

I'm using Postgres 9.3.5 and recently updated the hibernate from 3.2 to 4.3.11.

As a result I can't run "**SELECT... FOR UPDATE OF**" queries,
and simply 'select.. for update' is not enough in my case since it returns

> could not extract ResultSet. Reason: ERROR: FOR UPDATE cannot be applied to the nullable side of an outer join

The criteria I'm trying to use looks like this:

```
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(objectType).add(Restrictions.eq("name", objectName).ignoreCase());
```

I'm using the following locking:

in 3.2:     criteria.setLockMode(LockMode.UPGRADE);

in 4.3.11: criteria.setLockMode(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

I have an hierarchy of hibernate (& DB) objects which cause the hibernate perform several joins while constructing the above query. 
the 'objectType' is a **joined-subclass** of the main class

```
<class name="BaseObject" table="BASE_OBJECTS">
```

While using hibernate 3.2 the final query (taken from Postgres logs) ended with: "**for update of this_2_**"
(when **this_2_** is the alias given by hibernate to the main table (BaseObject) mapped in hbm.xml file)

After upgrading to 4.3.1.1 the same query returns the above mentioned exception.
which means the final query performed as **for update** (without the name of the table on which to perform the lock)

After an extensive look of the web I could find only that the "for update of" in hibernate with Postgres is not supported any more?

[https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5654][2]

It seems very unlikely since it's quite an important sql feature and a big degradation in usage.

Am I missing something here?

**02.09.15:**

I'll try to clarify myself:

using an example given in the hibernate documentation
at

> https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html

```
class name="Payment" table="PAYMENT">
<id name="id" type="long" column="PAYMENT_ID">
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>
<property name="amount" column="AMOUNT"/>
...
<joined-subclass name="CreditCardPayment" table="CREDIT_PAYMENT">
    <key column="PAYMENT_ID"/>
    <property name="creditCardType" column="CCTYPE"/>
    ...
</joined-subclass>
<joined-subclass name="CashPayment" table="CASH_PAYMENT">
    <key column="PAYMENT_ID"/>
    ...
</joined-subclass>
<joined-subclass name="ChequePayment" table="CHEQUE_PAYMENT">
    <key column="PAYMENT_ID"/>
    ...
</joined-subclass>
```

If I want to perform something like:
**select p from Payment p where id=1**

Hibernate will perform an outer join (on the key) on all tables .

Adding a lock (*.setLockMode(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)*) will lock the lines on the four tables (as 'For update'),
instead of only on table "Payments" ('for update of p') - which did happen in hibernate 3.2

So what We have, is that Something which was supplied earlier by hibernate, is not working any more, using their own mapping examples?

Thanks in advance
Marina

Comment: "*it's quite an important sql feature*" - maybe for you. But in 25 years of using relational database, I *never* had the need to use a `select for update` on a query using joins, let alone using outer joins.

Comment: In general, if you use an ORM you lose access to more advanced SQL features. This is one such case.

Comment: The ability to lock is hardly an advanced SQL feature. As you have very little control over Hibernate's use of outer joins there seems to be now obvious workaround either. I ran into the very same problem with a simple element collection.

Comment: Thanks!  Does it mean then, that the only way to upgrade the hibenrate in this case, will be with changing the queries themselves?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed in Hibernate 5.
Tested in 5.2.8.Final.